# Emails within Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hoping i can find a kind hearted person to help me if possible with some google sheets scripting.

I am looking for a way to automate something i currently have to do manually everyday.  I take data from present day I have entered into a spreadsheet, copy it, paste it into and email and send it.  I have used the Query function within Google sheets to help me separate who gets what information, that has made my life a tad bit easier.

I currently go to each tab, copy data, go to Gmail, paste data, type in the email address of the recipient, type in the subject, send, then go on to the next one 30+ times.

What I would like to do...
1. Click a menu item at top that says something like "Send Emails Now"
2. Once triggered, this would go to all (except 3, but i can just have these go to my own junk mail if too much) the tabs and send an email with the information contained only on that sheet to an email address in Cell A2

Email would have the subject "Call Parking Time XXXXXX"  where XXXX is the date in a E1

Here is a copy of the current sheet I have, some reason it will not let me share the original. So i have updated the 20-Sioux Falls and 21-Frederick sheets to show what i mean.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOgZzwbKEUF4_adkjxkvmiiVwFtu-2OGCPJ0Wj_keQU/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to s.o. please read the faq. This question does not qualify as there is no code or attempt. Please dont post a spec for someone to code for you. You could at least attempt to write some parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with Zig, here are a few things that'll help you get started:

```
//1. Define your Custom Menu Item
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Send Data', functionName: 'sendEmail_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Automated Emails', menuItems);
}
```

2. [Tutorial for Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) (Although this one sends data in each row as a separate email but you should get the idea of what to do)
3. [Sample for creating a table from Spreadsheet Data](http://www.googleappsscript.org/advanced-examples/create-table-from-sheet-data)

This should give you a good head-start. Put pieces of these together and you should be pretty much good to go. And if you hit any roadblocks along the way, people on SO are always glad to help. :)

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is what I needed, at least a point in the correct direction.  Because i was at ZERO and not sure where to even start.  THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an older question, I still have a recommendation for you and other potential users facing the same problem.

I use a Google Sheets add-on called [FormMule](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formmule-email-merge-util/kabhamaiihmaphgpijdolgcihofefajn?utm_source=permalink) that should work as a great solution to your challenge here. It allows you to create personalized template emails, set conditions for your merge, and have multiple templates to various people based upon your chosen criteria.
You can also set a time trigger, form submission trigger, or manually trigger it through the add-on menu.